# Исчезает кнопка

Tags: html, css, button

Есть кнопка, вот код:

```css
.new-game {
  width: 60.5%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
}

.new-game:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.new-game:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input class="new-game" value="New Game" type="button">
</form>
```

Почему если зажать на кнопку и увести мышку с нее она исчезает?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

к active добавь background

```css
.new-game {
  width: 60.5%;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  outline: none;
}

.new-game:hover {
  background-color: #e2e2e2;
}

.new-game:active {
  box-shadow: none;
  color: #f8f8f8;
   background-color: #e2e2e2;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input class="new-game" value="New Game" type="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, понял как работает.